# How to create an empty loop that runs for a given time in R

Tags: r

I need create an empty loop that runs for a given time, for example 2 hours. The loop just runs for nothing, no matter what it does, it is important that it loads R executions for exactly 2 hours.

for example, let's have some kind of script

```
model=lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris)
```

after this row there is an empty loop that does something for exactly 2 hours

```
for i....
```

after the empty loop has completed via 2 hours, continue to execute subsequent rows

```
summary(model)
predict(model,iris)
```

(no matter what row, it is important that in a certain place of code the loop wasted for 2 hours)

How it can be done?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Sys.sleep(7200)` ?

Comment: Is your presence at the computer being remotely monitored for 'activity' and you'd like to go bowling or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do this using a loop.

You can simply suspend all execution for `n` seconds by using `Sys.sleep(n)`. So to suspend for 2 hours you can use `Sys.sleep(2*60*60)`